# Move all file and folder to another folder in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I would like to take backup of all files and folder.

For example : i have 2 files and one folder which is in D:\Temp folder.

I have one more folder called "Backup" in the same folder i.e D:\Temp\

So i want to move all files and folders except Backup folder to Backup folder in Access VBA. Is that possible?

This is i tried so far from Ron's code.

I tried to move from one folder to temp folder, then from that to my original folder like below. But i am getting error.

```
savepath = "d:\test\"
savepath2 = "d:\temp\"
savepath1 = "d:\test\Archieve\"

Dim FSO As Object
Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String

FromPath = savepath  '<< Change
ToPath = savepath2 '<< Change

If Right(FromPath, 1) = "\" Then
    FromPath = Left(FromPath, Len(FromPath) - 1)
End If

If Right(ToPath, 1) = "\" Then
    ToPath = Left(ToPath, Len(ToPath) - 1)
End If

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
    MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
    Exit Sub
End If

FSO.moveFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath


If Not DirExists(savepath) Then
MkDir (savepath)
End If

If Not DirExists(savepath1) Then
MkDir (savepath1)
End If

FromPath = savepath2  '<< Change
ToPath = savepath1 '<< Change

If Right(FromPath, 1) = "\" Then
    FromPath = Left(FromPath, Len(FromPath) - 1)
End If

If Right(ToPath, 1) = "\" Then
    ToPath = Left(ToPath, Len(ToPath) - 1)
End If

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
    MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
    Exit Sub
End If


FSO.moveFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues: (1) You don't identify which line of code has the error, which makes others spend extra time looking at all your code;

(2) Your syntax is wrong - change

```
If Not DirExists(savepath) Then
```

to be:

```
If Not FSO.FolderExists(savepath) Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Also the move is not allowed in Windows 10. You’ll have to copy the files and/or folder and then delete it. If deleting a folder, you’ll need to make sure the folder is empty or you’ll get an error.